# Make neo4j query last long for testing purposes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We want to create a very slow query to test it in our application. Is there any way to make a Neo4j query last for a specific amount of seconds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you can use the APOC procedure [apoc.util.sleep](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index30.html#_utilities).

According the docs:

> `apoc.util.sleep({duration})`: sleeps for  millis, transaction
>   termination is honored

For example:

```
CALL apoc.util.sleep(1000) // wait for 1 second
MATCH (node) // match 'node'...
RETURN node // ... return 'node'
```

Please remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index30.html#_version_compatibility_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the execution guard by setting a value for [dbms.transaction.timeout](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/query-management/#transaction-timeout) in `neo4j.conf`. This will set the maximum time for a transaction to run.

By default the value is `0s` which disables the execution guard

Comment: no I wasn't asking for the execution guard. I was hoping to find a way to make a query run for a specific amount of time, or at least longer than one second.